# PHP mail adds www subdomain to From address

Tags: php, email, subdomain

I'm using the PHP mail function to send an email. Here's my code:

```
<?php
    $_SESSION['name'] = "My Name";
    $_SESSION['email'] = "myname@domain.com";
    $headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $_SESSION['name'] . ' <' . $_SESSION['email'] . '>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Cc: Someone Else <someone_else@domain.com>, ' . $_SESSION['name'] . ' <' . $_SESSION['email'] . '>';
    $msg = "Bar.";
    mail("recipient@domain.com","Foo",$msg,$headers);
?>
```

I've used an echo statement to confirm that $_SESSION['email'] is definitely set to myname@domain.com, but for some reason when it shows up in an inbox it claims its from myname@www.domain.com.

Why is it adding the www subdomain? Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Note: This will most likely have to do with your MTA (Mail Transport Agent), not with your PHP code.

Comment: Probably your MTA has a rewrite rule. This isn't really programming-related; nominating for migration to http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Its happening when I send an email from the terminal as well.

Comment: @Schtev how do you solve this problem? I am fetching the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and it turned the problem was in Postfix's `main.cf` file.

The file had:

```
myorigin = /etc/mailname
```

I changed that line to:

```
myorigin = $mydomain
```

then I did a reload of the postfix config file and it resolved the issue.